# How to define a clean-sheet HTML object?

Tags: css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop CSS styles to be applied in particular sections of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139447/stop-css-styles-to-be-applied-in-particular-sections-of-the-code)

HTML code inserted into `WordPress` with many plugins (each of them probably has it's own style) inherit global styles automatically.
An approach is to find unwanted styles and override them. Sometimes it's difficult to find it as in [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786090/unwanted-row-space-in-table))

How can I define an HTML object to be clean from base and don't inherit any style from the page ?

Comment: I prefer this question end up closing (if it's impossible as in question which you mentioned as duplicate) so maybe somebody in W3C think about the problem. With many plugins integrated into one page, it's a waste of time to find which one is affecting your object.

Comment: It's an interesting topic since you first have to define what "clean" is. Clean in IE looks different than clean in Firefox. Does clean also integrate reset styles, or is clean completely clean?

Comment: @Mike: I meant some amphibology but clean is clean and not reset. Why should accept some predefined styles and use `reset`. They should allow to build an object clean if it explicitly defines it.

Comment: Put that piece of html in an IFrame without css. There's no (other) way to disable css for a piece of a page.

Comment: @GolezTrol: thanks, I know that but doesn't help in my case. Is there anyway to find out which style is increasing row height in table?

Comment: No, as far as I know, there's no way to tell where a style is originating from. It could be a built in style, a piece of css (either separate, inline or in a style attribute) or have been set through Javascript (still in the style attribute). There's no way to tell the difference, apart from analysing the css. In a browser (I use Chrome) you can see this source, but I think you are looking for a more automatic solution.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I have set `height` of every object and still the table is dissoted. Take a look: http://aslani.id.ir/%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87/

Comment: I see, and I see your problem. But I wouldn't use a table for that at all. I'd use absolute positioned divs, or maybe even just an image map. Divs may suit you here. It's very unlikely that there's a common style defined for a div. You can put each image fragment in a div, put all fragments in a container div. The container div gets position: relative. The fragments get position absolute, causing them to be positioned absolutely *within the container*.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Can you guess what properties may disort a table? I'll check them myslef. I'm not a web designer and have no clue about this. Any point is appreciated.

Comment: I think I found it. It's the built-in style after all. I put it in an answer with a little context, because it was too long for a comment. (and it's an answer after all.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the browser, it's the built in style: the `border-spacing` is set to 2px.

I think you meant to clear this with `cellspacing=0`, but the page is an HTML5 page, which doesn't support this attribute.

That said, there's some advice for you. Using tables for mark-up is outdated. You may get away with it, but if you are creating an html 5 page, you should obey the rules that come with it. :) It turns out that it isn't any of the WordPress CSS that is bothering you. It was just the built-in style, which could not be overruled using outdated attributes. :)

For the future, in most browsers you can inspect the elements and their properties. In Chrome this is built in, in FireFox I think you still need to install the FireBug plugin. With that, you can right-click -> inspect element and then check the element or its parent to see what is going on:

[image: inspect CSS]

Comment: It was not that. It was `td` `vertical-align` but thanks for the time.

Comment: Glad you found it. I hope my explanation at least pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: @Golztrol: Yes, and thanks for your time. The question has no answer naturally but +1 is the least appreciation I can do.